# How do I extract this substring within this string?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have the following text:

```
"Showing1-30\nof 1404results"
```

What I want to pull out is the `1404`.

How do I do that?

I was thinking I would use a regexp to match just the string between the words `of` and `results`, but can't quite figure out how to do that.

Or is there another way, say a built-in Ruby method I could use that is efficient?

I was also considering using `split`, but the spacing is off so it looks like this:

```
=> ["Showing1-30", "of", "1404results"]
```

How do I do what I want?

Comment: Do you have more examples of the text you need to parse?

Comment: `"Showing1-30\nof 1404results"` is not overly readable. Are you in charge of generating it, or is it likely to change to something more readable, such as `"Showing 1-30\nof 1404 results"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use:

```
"Showing1-30\nof 1404results"[/(\d+)results/, 1] # => "1404"
```

`"Showing1-30\nof 1404results"` is not overly readable. If you are in charge of generating it, or if it is likely to change to something more readable, such as `"Showing 1-30\nof 1404 results"`, then a simple tweak will help:

```
"Showing1-30\nof 1404results"[/(\d+)\s*results/, 1] # => "1404"
```

where `\s*` will allow 0, 1 or multiple whitespace characters.

Keep regular expressions as simple as possible until it's proven they need to be more complex. As complexity increases the odds of slowing the match increases which, in a loop, can be drastic with long strings. Also, the odds of adding a hole that leads to false positives goes up too, which can be hard to debug.

Comment: Alas, but that regex (with "of ") has already been given in at two earlier answers, and I also mentioned `\s*` in my answer.

Comment: This is a nice modification of Peter's answer, and I guess addresses the core issue I raised. The only question is, if the text is fixed and now reads `"Showing 1 - 30 of 1404 results"`, will this still show `1404`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland, this doesn't care about `of`, which is inconsequential for finding the information. Only "results" is.

Comment: @marcamillion, I was extending the answer as you commented.

Comment: Good point. I much prefer the simpler regex, so I have switched the chosen answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could just do

```
["Showing1-30", "of", "1404results"].last.to_i
```

Or use a regex like

```
/of (\d+)results/
```

Comment: Oooohh...this is clever. The only thing is that someone may fix it, so that the last string has a space, therefore making the integer now be the 2nd to last string. Otherwise, I really like this suggestion. Quite sexy.

Answer (score 4):

Match "of" followed by one or more spaces, followed by one or more digits in capture group 1, followed by "results", then retrieve the contents of capture group 1.

```
"Showing1-30\nof 1404results"[/of\s+(\d+)results/,1]
  #=> "1404"
```

or

Match the string that is preceded by "of" followed by one<sup>1</sup> space (positive lookbehind) and is followed by "results" (positive lookahead)

```
"Showing1-30\nof 1404results"[/(?<=of\s)\d+(?=results)/]
  #=> "1404"
```

or

Match "of" followed by one or more spaces, forget everything matched so far  (`\K`), match one or more digits followed by "results" (positive lookahead)

```
"Showing1-30\nof 1404results"[/of\s+\K\d+(?=results)/]
  #=> "1404"
```

It may be desirable to change the first regex to

```
/(?<=of\s)\d+\s*(?=results)/
```

in case someone decides to "correct" the string to read `"Showing 1-30\nof 1404 results"[/(?<=of\s)\d+(?=results)/]`. (Same for the other two.)

<sup>1 Ruby's positive lookbehinds cannot be variable length; hence, `\s+` is not permitted here.</sup>

Comment: What a nice syntax, I didn't know it.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, I can't believe there is anything you don't know about regex's. Were you referring to `\K`?

Comment: No, it was about this specific ruby syntax: `"string"[/pattern/, group]` but I don't practice ruby very often.

Comment: Love this answer. Very thorough. Thanks for the explanations of everything!

Comment: I really do love this answer, but I prefer the simplicity of Tin Man's answer, so I am marking that one as the selected one. But I do love your suggestion and you deserve all the upvotes you have gotten. Thanks!

Comment: You may of course do what you wish, but I assume you realize that the only difference between @theTinMan's answer and my first one (and my comment about the string being "corrected") is that he didn't match on `"of "`, even though you proposed using `"of"` as one anchor, suggesting it had some significance (to avoid matching, say, "of first 100results".)

Comment: @CarySwoveland strictly speaking you are correct. I did specify using `of` as one anchor. But what TinMan pointed out to me is the more restrictions I put in the requirements is the more likely over time the regex will return false positives. The site owners can change the syntax any time and even remove the word `of`. If they do that, the entire regex fails even though the number I want is still the 2nd to last string -- which is what I really want anyway.

Comment: By that reasoning suppose we might suppose it could be changed to `str = "Showing1-30\nof 1404 trials"` (in which case you might want to use `str[/(\d+)\D*\z/,1].to_i #=> 1404 ` (select the last number in the string). We cannot say what would best meet your needs if you do not specify them precisely in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If the position of this number is fixed, the the following is the fastest

```
"Showing1-30\nof 1404results"[-12..-8]
```

The `[-12..-8]` is a range, you can see the string as an array of characters and specify the characters between the 8th and the 12th position counting from the right, -1 is the end of the line, -2 the last character etc..

In not, then a regular expression like

```
"Showing1-30\nof 14results"[/ \d+/].strip
```

You look for a space followed by a number, then you remove the leading space.
This is simpler than having to use a capture group.

Comment: You need to assume the length, as well as the position, of the number is fixed. Also, since the string begins "Showing1-30", we can assume it could be "Showing31-60" or possibly "Showing 31-60" unless we make a second assumption that there is no space preceding other numbers in the string. Also, considering that marcamillion is contemplating the use of  the strings "of" and "results" as anchors, perhaps there are strings to skip of the form "Showing1-30\nof 1404failures". My point is that more assumptions are needed to take this approach.

Comment: The position of the number may not be fixed unfortunately :(

The regexp won't necessarily work because there is no guarantee that the string will be identical to this (i.e. it could be fixed in the future to read `"Showing 1 - 30 of 1404 results"`) at which point that regex doesn't work. Nice attempt though!

Comment: marcamillon, this was not an attempt. It is correct given certain assumptions which could not be evaluated from the statement of the problem.

Comment: Thnx Cary.  @marcamillion: take a look at the title of your question "within this string" if there is no guarantee how your string is gonna look like you also can't use a regex, we would need more boundaries as to which form the string could be, As Paul commented from the beginning: we need more examples